# How do I share the internet connection of my PC with my Android/Cyanogenmod phone?

Tags: wireless, internet, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a wifi hotspot using my desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10502/create-a-wifi-hotspot-using-my-desktop)

I'd like to use my laptop's internet connection with my mobile. I've googled a lot and among other things followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/sharing-wireless-connection-with-other-pcs-and-phones?answertab=oldest#tab-top) procedure. But, even after my phone is rooted and all, I still cannot see the ad-hoc network that I create on my laptop using Ubuntu.

Now, further googling showed that I need to change the `wpa_supplicant` file in system/bin so that my wifi-direct will detect ad-hoc network created by my laptop.

Unfortunately, I've tried to find the file (with the correct settings), have tried a few other things as well, but to no avail. I was thinking maybe I'm doing something wrong or going about it the wrong way. Any help in the matter will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your laptop connected using the same WiFi adapter or is it connected to the internet in another way (e.g. wired ethernet or another WiFi adapter)? Only specific hardware is capable of running multi-mode simultaneously (both client/sta as well as master/AP/adhoc). And have you considered using regular a regular way to share the internet connection? (e.g. hotspot, rather than ad-hoc)

Comment: I'm connected to the internet on my laptop through Ethernet (its a company network). As for the hotspot part, I didn't try it yet. Not sure how that will work exactly but I was thinking I'll try other methods once I've exhausted every possible avenue on this one. I mean it should have worked, right ?

Comment: Unfortunately android does not support ad-hoc wifi mode